# Programmatically solving Sam Loyd's Battle of Hastings puzzle - performance issues with BigInt

Tags: javascript, optimization, integer, bigint, sqrt

I'm having performance issues when trying to check whether integer `n` is a perfect square (sqrt is a whole number) when using `BigInt`. Using normal numbers below `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` gives reasonable performance, but attempting to use `BigInt` even with the same number range causes a huge performance hit.

The program solves the [Battle of Hastings perfect square riddle put forth by Sam Loyd](https://www.mathsisfun.com/puzzles/sam-loyd-s-battle-of-hastings-puzzle.html) whereby my program iterates over the set of real numbers `n` (in this example, up to 7,000,000) to find instances where variable `y` [image] is a whole number (perfect square). I'm interested in the original square root of one of the 13 perfect squares where this condition is satisfied, which is what my code generates (there's more than one).

Assuming `y^2 < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` which is `2^53 – 1`, this can be done without `BigInt` and runs in ~60ms on my machine:

```js
const limit = 7_000_000;
var a = [];

console.time('regular int');

for (let n = 1; n < limit; n++) {
   if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(n, 2) * 13 + 1) % 1 === 0)
      a.push(n);
}
console.log(a.join(', '));

console.timeEnd('regular int');
```

Being able to use `BigInt` would mean I could test for numbers much higher than the inherent number variable limit `2^53 - 1`, but `BigInt` seems inherently slower; unusably so. To test whether a `BigInt` is a perfect square, I have to use a third party library as `Math.sqrt` doesn't exist for `BigInt` such that I can check if the root is perfect, as all `sqrt` returns a floor value. I adapted functions for this from a NodeJS library, [bigint-isqrt](https://github.com/Aisse-258/bigint-isqrt/blob/master/main.js) and [bigint-is-perfect-square](https://github.com/Aisse-258/bigint-is-perfect-square/blob/master/isFullSquare.js).

Thus, using `BigInt` with the same limit of 7,000,000 runs 35x slower:

```js
var integerSQRT = function(value) {
    if (value < 2n)
        return value;
   
    if (value < 16n)
        return BigInt(Math.sqrt(Number(value)) | 0);
    
    let x0, x1;
    if (value < 4503599627370496n)
        x1 = BigInt(Math.sqrt(Number(value))|0) - 3n;
    else {
        let vlen = value.toString().length;
        if (!(vlen & 1))
            x1 = 10n ** (BigInt(vlen / 2));
        else
            x1 = 4n * 10n ** (BigInt((vlen / 2) | 0));
    }
   
    do {
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = ((value / x0) + x0) >> 1n;
    } while ((x0 !== x1 && x0 !== (x1 - 1n)));
    return x0;
}

function perfectSquare(n) {
    // Divide n by 4 while divisible
    while ((n & 3n) === 0n && n !== 0n) {
        n >>= 2n;
    }
    // So, for now n is not divisible by 2
    // The only possible residual modulo 8 for such n is 1
    if ((n & 7n) !== 1n)
        return false;
    return n === integerSQRT(n) ** 2n;
}

const limit = 7_000_000;
var a = [];

console.time('big int');

for (let n = 1n; n < limit; n++) {
   if (perfectSquare(((n ** 2n) * 13n) + 1n))
      a.push(n);
}
console.log(a.join(', '));

console.timeEnd('big int');
```

Ideally I'm interested in doing this with a much higher limit than 7 million, but I'm unsure whether I can optimise the `BigInt` version any further. Any suggestions?

Comment: Whats the purpose of `.toString().length & 1`?

Comment: Unsure - it's from https://github.com/Aisse-258/bigint-isqrt/blob/master/main.js

Comment: Hm, I guess you'll always get a slowdown of some factors when using BigInts. I'd rather try to optimize away the loop over every single number, can't some of them be skipped?

Comment: Built-in functions are many times faster than the same function implemented purely in javascript. Instead of trying to make a "better" `sqrt`, avoid calculating square roots all together. Compare `m * m` with `13 * n * n + 1` and increase `m` or `n` in each cycle for whichever result is smaller. When the results are equal, you have your answer.

Comment: 35x slower sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be pleased to learn that [some recent improvements on V8](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=9407) have sped up the BigInt version quite a bit; with a recent V8 build I'm seeing your BigInt version being about 12x slower than the Number version.

A remaining challenge is that implementations of BigInt-`sqrt` are typically based on Newton iteration and hence need an estimate for a starting value, which should be near the final result, so about half as wide as the input, which is given by `log2(X)` or `bitLength(X)`. Until [this proposal](https://github.com/js-choi/proposal-bigint-bit-length) gets anywhere, that can best be done by converting the BigInt to a string and taking that string's length, which is fairly expensive.

To get faster right now, @Ouroborus' idea is great. I was curious how fast it would be, so I implemented it:

```
(function betterAlgorithm() {
  const limit = 7_000_000n;
  var a = [];

  console.time('better algorithm');

  let m = 1n;
  let m_squared = 1n;
  for (let n = 1n; n < limit; n += 1n) {
    let y_squared = n * n * 13n + 1n;
    while (y_squared > m_squared) {
      m += 1n;
      m_squared = m * m;
    }
    if (y_squared === m_squared) {
      a.push(n);
    }
  }
  console.log(a.join(', '));

  console.timeEnd('better algorithm');
})();
```

As a particular short-term detail, this uses `+= 1n` instead of `++`, because as of today, V8 hasn't yet gotten around to optimizing `++` for BigInts. This difference should disappear eventually (hopefully soon).

On my machine, this version takes only about 4x as much time as your original Number-based implementation.

For larger numbers, I would expect some gains from replacing the multiplications with additions (based on the observation that the delta between consecutive square numbers grows linearly), but for small-ish upper limits that appears to be a bit slower. If you want to toy around with it, this snippet describes the idea:

```
  let m_squared = 1n;         // == 1*1
  let m_squared_delta = 3n;   // == 2*2 - 1*1
  let y_squared = 14n;        // == 1*1*13+1
  let y_squared_delta = 39n;  // == 2*2*13+1 - 1*1*13+1
  for (let n = 1; n < limit; n++) {
    while (y_squared > m_squared) {
      m_squared += m_squared_delta;
      m_squared_delta += 2n;
    }
    if (y_squared === m_squared) {
      a.push(n);
    }
    y_squared += y_squared_delta;
    y_squared_delta += 26n;
  }
```

The earliest where this could possibly pay off is when the results exceed `2n**64n`; I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't measurable before `2n**256n` or so.

Comment: "which should be around log2(X) for best results" <- This doesn't seem quite right. Typically you want something that's already close to the square root, and a popular choice is the first power of two that exceeds the square root. That's where something like log2 / bit_length comes in: you want something along the lines of `2**(floor((bit_length(X) + 1) / 2)))`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson thanks for pointing that out; dunno what I was thinking. Fixed.